# How do I get parameters from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

JavaScript language.

I have a ReadFile function, it returns the contents of a json file to /data/user/0/com.mltrade.mltrade/data.json:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(67)] "{
    "name": "Bob",
    "mail": "google@gmail.com"
}
```

How do I get name and mail via javascript?

My code:

```
var data = mltrade.readFile('/data/user/0/com.mltrade.mltrade/data.json');
console.log(data);
// [INFO:CONSOLE(67)] "{
//     "name": "Bob",
//     "mail": "google@gmail.com"
// }

data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data.name); // undefined
```

Console:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(77)] "undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/javascript/app.js (77)
```

Comment: maybe the parse is failing. Can you try putting that inside a try...catch block and see if it throws anything?

Comment: Is `[INFO:CONSOLE(67)]` actually _in_ the JSON or is that just output from your terminal? If it's _in_ the JSON that's not valid JSON and won't parse.

Comment: [INFO:CONSOLE] is the output from the terminal.

Comment: How about that odd quote mark at the beginning of the JSON: `"{`. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: The quotation mark is part of [INFO:CONSOLE].

Comment: Why is there no matching quote at the end?

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show *after* `data = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: It looks like your `console.log()` puts quotes around everything, even if it's not a string, since it has quotes around `undefined`. That suggests that `mltrade.readFile()` already parsed the JSON and returned the object, so you don't need to parse it again.